# Bootstrap Datepicker appearing at incorrect location in a modal

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a button on a page that calls a modal having datepicker.

If this button is at top (I don't have to scroll page to click), modal opens and datepicker displays correctly.

But if this button is lower on the page( so that I have to scroll page to click), modal opens and datepicker displays incorrect.
(NOT SURE if scrolling has a relation)

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneCoder/kdLehcwg/)

Here's the image displaying problem, the datepicker should display above as a tooltip, but it goes down :
[image]

Here's the code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#callModal">Contact</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="callModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="contact">Contact</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Your mobile number">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="cal">Date &amp; Time</label>
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="cal"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
              </script>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Contact </button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**EDIT** 
The datetimepicker tooltip is shifted by the amount by which I scroll the page before clicking the button "Contact" to appear the modal containing the datetimepicker.

Comment: I wouldn't say "wrong" position, as this is the intended behaviour of datetimepicker, but you want it above, not below, right? Currently, I don't think there's an option for `orientation`, like there is with the `datepicker` plugin.

Comment: @TimLewis : It is not coming below. Its off-positioned, as otherwise there would have been an arrow with  datepicker box like tooltips have.

Comment: Hmm... Well, I can't seem get your fiddle to work... 2 console errors: `moment is not defined` and `$(...).datetimepicker() is not a function`.

Comment: @TimLewis  : I have added momenjs file but I don't know why I am getting `datetimepicker()` is not a function on the fiddle, even if its js file is added.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue.  I was able to solve it by adding a container attribute to the div.

```
$('#myDatePicker').datepicker({
  container:'#myModalId'
});
```

or if you are using the "lazy load" method as I was:

```
<input id='myDatePicker' data-provide='datepicker' data-date-container='#myModalId'>
```

Reference : http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: should this solve the issue if it's inside a div with overflow: scroll ?

Comment: your answer is invalid because the question was about datetimepicker not datepicker

Comment: This doesn't work. No calendar modal is displayed. I get an uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Answer (score 28):

Datetimepicker will show in a wrong place if the container of the input is not positioned relative.

The solution is:

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
</div>
```

Comment: this solved for me when using datetimepicker inside a bootstrap accordian

Comment: My calendar was only showing up incorrectly for smaller window sizes, this did the trick, thanks so much!

Comment: this was really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem when using it with Bootstrap 4.1.1. The datepicker popover was appeareing on to the top of the input element.

I fixed it using this CSS:

```
/* fix bootstrap-datepicker positional bug */
.datepicker {
  transform: translate(0, 3.1em);
}
```

Comment: I just had the same problem. This fixed it, along with [Shadi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698209/4262446) answer. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too with  =>   transform: translate(0, 7.4em);

Answer (score 4):

In my case the position of the datepicker was 60px higher than it should have been, because one of its `div` parents had:

<s>`margin-top: 60px;`</s>

instead of

```
padding-top: 60px;
```

Answer (score 2):

For me below solution is working

```
var datepicker = sandbox.dom('body').find('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget:last'),

position = datepicker.offset();

// Move datepicker to the exact same place it was but attached to the body
datepicker.appendTo('body');
datepicker.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: position.top,
    bottom: 'auto',
    left: position.left,
    right: 'auto'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this and related issues turned out to be because I had the code inspector window open. Regular users shouldn't have this on, so if that's your case it's a non issue.

Comment: That's weird, maybe it's a responsiveness issue then?

Answer (score 0):

This solutions worked perfectly for me to render the datepicker on top of bootstrap modal.

http://jsfiddle.net/cmpgtuwy/654/

HTML

```
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
Some content goes here<br />
Some more content.
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">

<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="input-group date" id="dtp">
<input type="text" class="form-control" />  
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#dtp').datetimepicker({
format: 'MMM D, YYYY',
widgetParent: 'body'});


$('#dtp').on('dp.show', function() {
      var datepicker = $('body').find('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget:last');
      if (datepicker.hasClass('bottom')) {
        var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var left = $(this).offset().left;
        datepicker.css({
          'top': top + 'px',
          'bottom': 'auto',
          'left': left + 'px'
        });
      }
      else if (datepicker.hasClass('top')) {
        var top = $(this).offset().top - datepicker.outerHeight();
        var left = $(this).offset().left;
        datepicker.css({
          'top': top + 'px',
          'bottom': 'auto',
          'left': left + 'px'
        });
      }
    });
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
height: 100px;
overflow: auto;}
body {
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe is not the most elegant solution but for me it worked

```
  //fixing scroll issue on datepicker
  $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").on("click", function() {
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({top: xxx});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".yourInputField").on("click", function() {
    var offsetModal = $('#yourModalID').offset().top;
    var offsetInput = $(this).offset().top;
    var inputHeight = $(this).height();
    var customPadding = 17; //custom modal padding (bootstrap modal)! 
    var topDatepicker = (offsetInput + inputHeight + customPadding) - offsetModal;
  $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({top: topDatepicker});
});
```