# Show datapicker on valid input text

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I test this datapicker: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

The problem is, datapicker show on valid input text. Here is my HTML code:

```
<span class="input-box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Treść notatki..." name="msg-box" id="msg-box-'.$results['USER_ID'].'" class="datepicker_message_div" />
    <div data-date="'.$results['TOMORROW_DATE'].'" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" class="input-append date datepicker datepicker_div">
        <span style="border-right: none;" class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Data powiadomienia" value="" title="Data powiadomienia (parametr nieobowiązkowy)" id="date-box-'.$results['USER_ID'].'"  data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" class="span11" >
        <button class="btn btn-success chat_msg_save" id="chat_msg_save_'.$results['USER_ID'].'">Zapisz</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="chat_current_edit_'.$results['USER_ID'].'" value="">
</span>
```

and here is screenshot:

[image]

So I have two input type text and datepicker show on valid. It should print in the second input text, not on the first which is input for send text message. How I can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you want the datepicker attached to the input with id `id="date-box-'.$results['USER_ID'].'"`

According to [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html) you can add an attribute to your input :

```
data-date-container="date-box-'.$results['USER_ID'].'"
```

Comment: I attached this datapicker for 100 elements, so every #date-box has other ID. I have to add your code 100 times? Or I can add once the classname of this element?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: It still show on valid input. I tried also add: `inputs: $('.datepicker_show_module'),` inside datepicker init function and set the class `datepicker_show_module` for my input but it still show on valid input.

Comment: This should work. Have a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29000794/7652544

Answer (score -1):

you can set like this

```
  var FirstTextBoxVal=$(".datepicker_message_div").val();



    $(".date-box-Text").val(FirstTextBoxVal);
```